# Is there a way to copy rotation beyond 180 degres with bone constraints?

Tags: rigging

Is there any way I can configure bone constrains to copy rotational values beyond 180? The bones "pops" to -180 when I reach 180. This is for a longer chain of bones that should be able to twist more than that.

I could solve this using drivers but I find constraints to be cleaner and easier to overview. Also using drivers to copy rotation from a controlling bone to a deforming is tedious.

Side note: In my investigations, I found out that there is an interesting side effect of using rotations outside the -180 - 180 range: Dual Quaternion cannot handle it. Dual Quaternion deformation is enabled using *Preserve Volume* on the Armature Modifier.

[image]

Here is a file with a minimal setup.
The Controller bone should control the 3-bone chain with Y local rotation.

[image]

Comment: maybe your problem is that you need to switch your bone rotation from Quaternion to Euler in the N panel?

Comment: No, I have tried that, the rotation seems to be copied in quaternion no matter what is used on the pose bones.

Comment: In Euler mode, if you enter the value in the N panel and create keyframes, it works. Or I miss something in your explanation and please be more precise

Comment: Added a minimal setup in a blend file.

Comment: When I rotate the controller 300° in the N panel with 2 keyframes, it rotates bones 06 and 07

Comment: yes, it rotates but the rotation constrains will only work with source rotation from -180 to 180 degres. You will see this behaviour when you rotate the controller outside that range as a "pop". It simply rotates the over way.

Comment: oh ok I see the problem now, I have to go so I hope someone will tell

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97283/discussion-between-jackdaw-and-moonboots).

Comment: I've noticed that same problem with IK chains.  It's pretty annoying

Comment: If you put the Influence at 1 it works, so the flip happens because of that, it comes back to its 0 position as soon as it reaches the value you've assigned, I guess the solution is the Transformation constraint as explained here but I'm still struggling: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaOzY-vN7TY

Comment: The flip is there anyway but it's hidden because it's doing a full flip from 180 to -180.  Thank you for trying to help me.